# (SSRS) - Extracting <AutoRefresh> Value from [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] with XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, reporting-services

I'd like to extract the value (as an INT) for `<AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>` from the `[ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog]` table.  I know I can do some string manipulation with SUBSTRING/CHARINDEX, but I'd ideally like to extract this using proper XML.

An example of the XML (Once it's been converted) can be found here:

http://pastebin.com/S1vWW9BT

Can anyone help?

Here's the code to get the column from a VARBINARY to XML:

```
SELECT TOP 13 C.ItemID
    ,C.NAME AS [ReportName]
    ,CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), C.CONTENT))) 
          AS [ReportDeffinitionXML]
FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] AS C WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE C.Type = 2
```

Comment: What is the format of the `ReportDeffinitionXML` XML?

Comment: Post sample XML you have, otherwise no one will be able to answer this question

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: Everything you need to get started is here: http://bretstateham.com/extracting-ssrs-report-rdl-xml-from-the-reportserver-database/ Basically now you've got the xml as an xml datatype, you'll use xquery methods within t-sql to retrieve specific values into a result set.

Comment: Apologies.  Please find a link to an example of the XML (once it's been converted to XML):

http://pastebin.com/S1vWW9BT

(Value of interest is on line 2)

@SASFROG - Thanks - I had previously seen this blog - however the code splits the values out to a different line.  I need the extracted value(s) to be on one row per Report.

Comment: So when you used the technique from the blog, what were you getting one row per? Seems to me it's trivial to adapt the code there to get what you want. Maybe post your attempted code and we can help more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was given by a MS employee Shrek Li at the below link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f948ffee-8a3e-4717-b7f7-52e0f280fd4e/ssrs-extracting-autorefresh-value-from-reportserverdbocatalog-with-xml?forum=sqlreportingservices

Please note that your relevant XML scheme needs to be referenced:

```
WITH xmlnamespaces(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition'),CTE AS(SELECT
   TOP 50
   C.ItemID,
   C.Name AS [ReportName],
   CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), C.CONTENT))) AS [ReportDeffinitionXML] FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] AS C WHERE
   C.Type = 2) SELECT ItemID, [ReportName], [ReportDeffinitionXML], ReportDeffinitionXML].value('(/Report/AutoRefresh)[1]', 'int' ) AS [AutoRefreshValue] FROM CTE
```